# how to program excell that change cell value if another cell has value?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2010, excel-2003, vba

I am new in Excel programming. 
I am trying to accomplish one operation where I have to change value of excel cell when other cell has value on it. else the value should not have to change and it will remail as previous result one.

So let me explaine more about it
I have my fund of month in B3 (1000)(number)
say for I have value in B5 to B36 (numbers)(Represent as each day expense)
I will add one value each day for the current month.
at the emd of the month I have remaining balance of my fund.
I will remove days use (B5:b36) at each month. But my remaining balance should not have to remove.

Prob. 1) I want to that remaining balance stored in some cell automatically.

Prob. 2) I want to Sum my remainig balance and next month fund for next month.

I know there are lots of good Programmer who can help me with this ...

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `I know there are lots of good Programmer who can help me with this ` ... there sure are, but you will get **much** more help if you post what you've tried to do and why it's failing. Also, a screenshot will help us understand your question as well. It's pretty vague as written.

Answer (score 1):

I am having trouble understanding your exact question. But in general, to sum you use the "sum" formula. So, say you want to sum each day's expenses for a monthly total, you would put this formula into the cell that you want the total in:

```
=Sum(B5:B36)
```

To get the remaining balance (if I understand you right), your formula would be:

```
=B3-Sum(B5:B36)
```

Then for the next month you can just reference the cell above. So say it was B37, then you would reference it by:

```
=B37
```

I hope this helps, but as I said, I was unable to fully understand your question(s).